# Adding a 2012 R2 server to a 2008 R2 SharePoint 2010 farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update

Having an issue where configuration is looking for SharePoint 2010 updates/patches that it sees on other servers in the farm. What is the best way to get all the updates/patches that are missing when the automatic update won't pull them?

Ultimate goal will be to have the following configuration:

WFE1-Server2008
WFE2-Server2008
WFE3-Server2012 (this is the new server i'm trying to add to the farm)
APP1-Server2008

**UPDATE W/MISSING PATCHES:**

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 Installed Across Server Farm 
 Microsoft Word Server

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3127950) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7176.5000)
 Missing on WFE1
Missing on WAPPS1
Missing on WFE2 
 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3118377) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7174.5001)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Excel Services Components

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3118381) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7176.5000)
 Missing on WFE1
Missing on WAPPS1
Missing on WFE2 
 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3115119) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7173.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Office Server Proof (English) 2010

Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3055040) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7151.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft SharePoint Portal

Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3055040) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7155.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft SharePoint Portal English Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7113.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Slide Library

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7109.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 PerformancePoint Services for SharePoint

Update for 2010 Microsoft Business Productivity Servers (KB2880521) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7160.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 1033 Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7109.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Visio Services Web Front End Components

Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3055040) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7149.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Excel Services English Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7109.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Access Services Server

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7113.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Access Services English Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7109.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Web Analytics Web Front End Components

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7124.5000)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Web Analytics English Language Pack

Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2883103) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7109.5000)
 Missing Locally

**UPDATE: (after applying august cu as mentioned below)**

Looks like that took care of most of them. Thanks to you both for that idea. I'm still seeing the following and when I try to manually download and install the patches listed as missing I get the message that they're already installed.

Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 Installed Across Server Farm 
 Microsoft Word Server

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3127950) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7176.5000)
 Missing on WFE1
Missing on WAPPS1
Missing on WFE2 
 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3118377) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7174.5001)
 Missing Locally 
 Microsoft Excel Services Components

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3118381) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7176.5000)
 Missing on WFE1
Missing on WAPPS1
Missing on WFE2 
 Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB3115119) 64-Bit Edition (14.0.7173.5000)
 Missing Locally

Comment: what you trying to acheeive? adding a new server into SharePoint but it is complaining about the missing patches? are they sharepoint patch or windows? what is patch level of the SharePoint?

Comment: Our two current WFEs are struggling and we really can't touch them. Our goal was to add a new 2012 R2 server into the mix that we can control better (raise/lower server specs). Once the new server has been added to the farm we will have 1 web application and a couple services run on it. When I ran the configuration setup it showed a bunch (10+) of missing updates locally. I clicked on the missing updates and manually downloaded them but they say that they are already installed. If this isn't enough information I can provide the specific missing updates tomorrow when I get to work.

Comment: From central admin you can check on what patch your farm is? Also share the list of missing patch

Comment: The farm is on: 14.0.7171.5000. I've updated the original post with the missing patches.

Comment: can you go to the central admin > upgrade and migration > Check product and patch installation status...Check which is KB has highest build number? I am thinking may be your farm is July CU but if you get the latest number from that page, really helpful

Comment: Under there it looks like: 14.0.7015.1000

Comment: no, it should be higher, 7015 is SP2.  I think try to install the SP2 + August CU 2015 on new server then run the config wizard

Comment: I had to reboot all the servers and start some services manually after but this seems to be the part that was missing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please outlined the steps which help you to resolve the issue...this is good for community.

Comment: Sure thing. Should I do it in a comment or click the answer my question button?

Comment: add as an answer. which will be visible to everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the latest build numbers on your list, it looks like you are missing the [August 2015 CU package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3055040).  You can find the list of Build Numbers at [SharePoint Server build numbers](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sharepoint/).

You'll have to install that package to your new server to add the server to the farm.  You must have SP2 installed to install the package, so if your installation of SharePoint on the new server did not include SP2, make sure to install it first.

Comment: I had to reboot all the servers and start some services manually after but this seems to be the part that was missing. Thanks for the help!